# How can I capture rsync progress messages in Perl?

Tags: perl, rsync

I want to capture all the progress messages emitted by an rsync process from a Perl script. In certain circumstances this isn't working.

Here's a typical rsync command line I use:

```
rsync -aL --verbose --progress --bwlimit=100 \
  --include-from=/tmp/78hJ2eDCs1 \
  --include '*/' --exclude '*' \
  /srcdir/* \
  hostname:/target/ 2>&1
```

If I run this within a bash shell, I'll see something like this:

```
Building file list ...
1600 files...
1700 files...
and so on
```

If I try the same command within Perl, I get the "Building file list" output OK, but not the status updates. Here's how I test the capture

```
my $pid = open(OUTPUT, "$cmd |")  or die "Couldn't fork: $!\n";

my $ch;
while(read(OUTPUT, $ch, 1)==1)
{
    print $ch;
}
close(OUTPUT);
```

My guess is that either rsync senses the output handle isn't a typical console, or is being output in some unusual manner that I'm not capturing. *However, what makes it even odder is that if I omit the --include and --exclude filters, I can capture the status messages just fine.*

Anyone any clues as to what is going on?

Comment: After the two answers already provided, I'm guessing that it's something that rsync is doing to buffer the output.  Do you get all the output at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the solution was simple - I just had to unbuffer the IO in my script with `$| = 1;`

I'm still puzzled by how I observed the problem with some rsync options and not others. Thankyou Paul Tomblin and dsm for giving me ideas.

Comment: Funny, I thought $| and ->autoflush were equivalent, that's why I suggested it.

Comment: I guess that autoflush acted on the OUTPUT handle, while $| was acting on the scripts STDOUT? i.e. somehow I just wasn't getting the output flushed?

Answer (score 4):

Does perl buffer the output from pipes?  If so, you might be able to get it working if after you open the OUTPUT handle, you turn off buffering with OUTPUT->autoflush(1);

Comment: I tried that to no avail - the odd thing is that I *can* capture all the output if I don't use the --include/exclude options.

Answer (score 4):

you could use [Expect.pm](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod), which mimics a PTY, that may give you the output you are looking for.

Failing that, you could try the [`--stats`](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) or [`--progress`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/rsync/) options.

Comment: Not sure I can just iteratively eat the output with Expect, but the idea of mimicking a pseudo TTY might prove fruitful...will explore that.

Comment: Nope, I tried using IO::Pty::Easy and I saw the exact same behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to use IPC::Run and it's callbacks for data on stdout/stderr.

Answer (score 0):

[Suffering from Buffering?](http://perl.plover.com/FAQs/Buffering.html) is best explanation about buffering effect I found so far. Well worth the time to read and understand.

Don't forget that buffering is there for a reason so don't just blinding turn it off for every possible problem.